# Webcam microphone input in Gnome/pulseaudio

Tags: linux, audio, gnome, webcam

Just got a "Trust" webcam, which gets recognized on my Ubuntu Lucid. It has a built in microphone - which also gets recognized - however, I cannot really get it to act as the system microphone input?

Here are some screenshots of what is shown by `gnome-volume-control`:

The default window shows Trust webcam - which has two profiles: "Analog Mono Input" and "Off" - of course, I have it on "Analog Mono Input":

[image: micwebcam5.png]

However, on the "Input" tab - there is no matching "device for sound input" - neither a matching connector:

[image: micwebcam6-7.png]

Then I installed `pavucontrol` - but that doesn't show that much more; it tells first that `gnome-volume-control` reads from "Internal Audio Analog Stereo":

[image: micwebcam1.png]

Then in "Input devices" tab, there is again nothing resembling the mic input from webcam:

[image: micwebcam2-3.png]

Finally, under "Configuration" tab, the "Trust" webcam shows, but even if its profile is on "Analog Mono Input", nothing much happens:

[image: micwebcam4.png]

So, does anyone know how I could get this webcam microphone to be recognized as the system input?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: This question is related: [linux - Sound input issue with skype, selecting a microphone? - Unix and Linux - Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/sound-input-issue-with-skype-selecting-a-microphone) - however, notice that (as per that answer) even with a skype call running, I can never select the microphone for the webcam ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.. another day, another reboot ... and now, for some reason, all the needed devices show ?!

Note that I'm booting Ubuntu Lucid from a USB key (with persistent mode)... And the only difference I can see in respect to the OP, is that in the OP, the system was booted first - and then the camera attached; while now, the camera was already attached while the system was booting... Cannot really tell if that makes a difference.

However here are some screenshots; first of `gnome-volume-control`:

[image: micwebcam10.png]

... and also of `pavucontrol`:

[image: micwebcam11.png]

Well, nice this got sorted on its own (sort of) :) Other than that, hope this can assist someone else in similar situation..

Cheers!